# Matching character lists of unequal length

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I want to match two lists from which one list is smaller while other is a bigger one. If a match occurs between two lists then put the matching element in a new list at the same index instead of putting it another index. You can understand my question from the code given below:

```
list1=['AF','KN','JN','NJ']
list2=['KNJ','NJK','JNJ','INS','AFG']
matchlist = []
smaller_list_len = min(len(list1),len(list2))


for ind in range(smaller_list_len):
    elem2 = list1[ind]
    elem1 = list2[ind][0:2] 

    if elem1 in list2:
       matchlist.append(list1[ind])
```

***Obtained output***

```
>>> matchlist
['KNJ', 'NJK', 'JNJ']
```

***Desired Output***

```
>>> matchlist
['AFG', 'KNJ', 'JNJ', 'NJK']
```

Is there a way to get the desired output?

Comment: Is the list with the smaller length always going to have 2 character strings and the longer list going to have 3 character strings? Is list1 always going to be the smaller list?

Comment: Yes it can have two character strings and the second list is three character string

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop iterating over the 3-char list. When an item in that list contains the current item in the 2-char list, append it and break out of the inner loop:

```
list1=['AF','KN','JN','NJ']
list2=['KNJ','NJK','JNJ','INS','AFG']
matchlist = []
smaller_list_len = min(len(list1),len(list2))


for ind in range(smaller_list_len):
    for item in list2:
        if list1[ind] in item:
            matchlist.append(item)
            break
```

Comment: NJ matches KNJ first... your question doesn't explain why it should skip over KNJ

Answer (score 0):

Given the question doesn't specify any constraints, in a more pythonic way, using a list comprehension:

```
list1=['AF','KN','JN','NJ']
list2=['KNJ','NJK','JNJ','INS','AFG']

matchlist=[e2 for e1 in list1 for e2 in list2 if e2.startswith(e1)]
```

produces

```
['AFG', 'KNJ', 'JNJ', 'NJK']
```